# Can't use xming with putty, Windows 7 locally on remote Linux

Tags: xming

I have used xLaunch, Multiple Windows, Start no client, Clipboard, No Access Control, no additional parameters or font server -- that is, defaults all the way.

On Putty,

When I connect to the remote Linux system, I get a delay, followed by this message:
    /usr/bin/xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/{userName}/.Xauthority

When I try to start an xterm (`xterm &`), I see

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 data did not match
PuTTY X11 proxy: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 data did not match
PuTTY X11 proxy: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 data did not match
PuTTY X11 proxy: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 data did not match
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

(end of lines inserted so you can read)

`localhost:10.0` looked funny to me, so I forced `DISPLAY` to be `localhost:10.0`.  The complaint is now

```
No protocol specified
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0
```

Changing it to the actual IP of my local machine gets me the same message, but with more copies of "No protocol specified."

Thanks for all help --

Comment: Some ideas:  1) Run sshd in debug mode. Might get more information. 2) Check the permissions on your .Xauthority file.  Or delete it and let sshd create a new one. 3) Disable SElinux.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use `xterm` as your own login, but unable to once `su`'ing to root, then there's an program called `sux`, which sorts the magic cookie out when moving from one user to another.

It's a bit of a security risk, and not to be used in a production environment, but works nicely for a home setup.

Otherwise look at a user that works,

```
pompt> xauth list
```

(Note down the following output)

```
10-111-11-11/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ce4867d5a6c0e6d5f33285aa0e163987
```

Then do this:

```
prompt> su – useryouwanttowork
```

(Add entire output using `xauth add` command)

```
prompt> xauth add 10-111-11-11/unix:10 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ce4867d5a6c0e6d5f33285aa0e163987
```