# X11 Forwarding via Proxy Tunnel

Tags: x11, putty, squid

I am trying to run windowed applications on a private server that I connect to via Putty with HTTP Proxy Tunnel (Squid server on another host). I can connect fine to the Host's CLI, but whenever I try to run "xclock" or "gedit", it gives the error below:

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 data did not matchPuTTY X11 proxy: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 data did not matchPuTTY X11 proxy: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 data did not matchPuTTY X11 proxy: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 data did not matchError: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

I doublechecked my /etc/ssh/sshd_config and all the configuration seems correct. Is there any extra configurations that I have to set on the Squid config?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't use xming with putty, Windows 7 locally on remote Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774775/cant-use-xming-with-putty-windows-7-locally-on-remote-linux)

Comment: Not really sir. It works when I am not using SSH tunnel over HTTP proxy. In the office I can SSH directly to the remote host. But when I am at home I have no choice but to use HTTP proxy tunneling. That is when I am encountering the MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE mismatch.

Comment: SSH has XSECURITY support built in. Putty... well, one can hope, some day maybe.